# Opposite of a function being bijective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, terminology

A function is **bijective** if it is both **surjective** and **injective**. Is there a term for when a function is both **not surjective** and **not injective**?

Comment: Although, to be fair, one would think that the "opposite" would be not surjective or not injective.

Comment: i don't quite mean literal opposite, as people in english don't really mean "one, the other, or both" when they say "or;" they typically mean a dichotomy of the two ideas (in contrast to $\vee$, or the $or$ operator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't.  The concept of a "non-surjective and non-injective function" just doesn't generally arise often enough to need a special term.

Comment: Well, it could refer to a function that generates random numbers, couldn't it?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien (1) That isn't really a function. (2) Ilmari didn't say the concept never arises, simply that it does not arise often enough to need a special term. Finding one example where the concept arises does not mean the term is now useful...

Comment: @5xum In response to (1), sorry, my mind went out of math mode and into programming mode. In response to (2), the question was really based upon inquiry, not contradiction (that is, it was not my intention to disprove the conjecture).

Comment: i wonder, though: what if there was a term? what might it be?

Comment: @NobodyHere Nonjectve?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien oh wow that makes sense

Answer (score -3):

Of course not. This would be a useless notion (so there is no need for such terminology). Most functions are not surjective or injective (in the sense that if you take a "random" one, then you cannot expect it to be surjective or injective), mind you. We are mostly interested in the special class of mappings called injections and surjections, and for this reason the terminology "injective" and "surjetive" is useful.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it *useless*. I would more mildly say *not useful enough*.

Comment: @5xum: in a sense I agree, but on the other hand I feel that saying it is useless is somewhat more to the point

Comment: Downvoted because of the phrasing "of course not", which is overly aggressive for a question asked in good faith by a potential beginner.